# In css or jquery, is there a way I can add something to my border on a div?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Is there a way I can put little squares around a div to make it look like handles, one top middle, top left, top right, middle left, middle right, bottom left, bottom right, bottom middle.  I have this jquery plugin and I have a div resizeable, but I wanted to know how I could make it look like it has handles.  Most likely in css, but maybe theres a way in jquery?  Open to either suggestions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `<div>` is not `static`-ally positioned, (`position: relative` works too) then anything within it which is `absolute`-ly positioned will refer to it.  Makes nice handles.

Comment: could you give me an example?

Comment: parent set position:relative, 8 children set position:absolute and has  top, right, bottom and left spacing valued respectively in 0%, 50% or 100%.  Border images might work, but that means you’re baking how the handles look into something larger.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your app, (and what you need to support) the CSS3 property [border-image](http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/) may be an option. If the border is used to indicate JavaScript functionality, this CSS would be best applied with JavaScript in a progressively enhanced manner.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a bottom-right positioned background image. See http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/

Check the jQuery UI Resizable demo - see how they've done it?